# How to capture arbitrary paths at one route in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm serving **React** app from **FastAPI** by
mounting

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

@app.route('/session')
async def renderReactApp(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

by this React app get served and React routing also works fine at client side
but as soon as client reloads on a route which is not defined on server but used in React app FastAPI return `not found` to fix this I did something as below.

- `@app.route('/network')`
- `@app.route('/gat')`
- `@app.route('/session')`

---

```
async def renderReactApp(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

but it seems weird and wrong to me as I need to add every route at the back-end as well as at frontend.

I'm sure there must be something like Flask `@flask_app.add_url_rule('/<path:path>', 'index', index)` in FastAPI which will server all arbitrary path

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: hey @YagizcanDegirmenci I'm not getting any error

Comment: Does this helps? [returning react frontend from fastapi backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928450/how-to-put-backend-and-frontend-together-returning-react-frontend-from-fastapi)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not looking for a way to render a web app.
I am looking for a way in FastAPI using which (single route) I can serve multiple route requests.
`@app.route("/some-route")
def serveAllRoute():
  # servers /some-route as well as /another-woute
`

Comment: Ah got it, needed this explanation, check my answer below.

Comment: I have this same issue. What is `templates` in this code?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Since FastAPI is based on Starlette, you can use what they call "converters" with your route parameters, using type `path` in this case, which "returns the rest of the path, including any additional `/` characers."

See https://www.starlette.io/routing/#path-parameters for reference.

If your react (or vue or ...) app is using a base path, you can do something like this, which assigns anything after `/my-app/` to the `rest_of_path` variable:

```
@app.get("/my-app/{rest_of_path:path}")
async def serve_my_app(request: Request, rest_of_path: str):
    print("rest_of_path: "+rest_of_path)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

If you are not using a unique base path like `/my-app/` (which seems to be your use case), you can still accomplish this with a catch-all route, which should go after any other routes so that it doesn't overwrite them:

```
@app.route("/{full_path:path}")
async def catch_all(request: Request, full_path: str):
    print("full_path: "+full_path)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

(In fact you would want to use this catch-all regardless in order to catch the difference between requests for `/my-app/` and `/my-app`)

Comment: Assuming there are other static files in addition to `index.html` (e.g. JS, CSS, asset files) in the OP's static directory that he has mounted i.e. `app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")`, won't this strategy prevent those being served by fastapi?

Comment: @mecampbellsoup no it shouldn't interfere with that if you have the `catch_all` after the static definition, and after all other routes for that matter. You want your catch-all method at the end. In fact, React builds tend to have html, js and css files that all get stashed in the static dir -- this approach will serve all of those files and others as expected.

Comment: missing 1 required positional argument: 'rest_of_path'

Answer (score 9):

As @mecampbellsoup pointed out: there are usually other static files that need to be served with an application like this.

Hopefully this comes in handy to someone else:

```py
import os
from typing import Tuple

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()


class SinglePageApplication(StaticFiles):
    """Acts similar to the bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback
    NPM package."""

    def __init__(self, directory: os.PathLike, index='index.html') -> None:
        self.index = index

        # set html=True to resolve the index even when no
        # the base path is passed in
        super().__init__(directory=directory, packages=None, html=True, check_dir=True)

    async def lookup_path(self, path: str) -> Tuple[str, os.stat_result]:
        """Returns the index file when no match is found.

        Args:
            path (str): Resource path.

        Returns:
            [tuple[str, os.stat_result]]: Always retuens a full path and stat result.
        """
        full_path, stat_result = await super().lookup_path(path)

        # if a file cannot be found
        if stat_result is None:
            return await super().lookup_path(self.index)

        return (full_path, stat_result)



app.mount(
    path='/',
    app=SinglePageApplication(directory='path/to/dist'),
    name='SPA'
)
```

These modifications make the StaticFiles mount act similar to the [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) NPM package.

Answer (score 9):

## Simple and effective solution compatible with `react-router`

I made a very simple function that it is fully compatible `react-router` and `create-react-app` applications (most use cases)

### The function

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates


def serve_react_app(app: FastAPI, build_dir: Union[Path, str]) -> FastAPI:
    """Serves a React application in the root directory `/`

    Args:
        app: FastAPI application instance
        build_dir: React build directory (generated by `yarn build` or
            `npm run build`)

    Returns:
        FastAPI: instance with the react application added
    """
    if isinstance(build_dir, str):
        build_dir = Path(build_dir)

    app.mount(
        "/static/",
        StaticFiles(directory=build_dir / "static"),
        name="React App static files",
    )
    templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=build_dir.as_posix())

    @app.get("/{full_path:path}")
    async def serve_react_app(request: Request, full_path: str):
        """Serve the react app
        `full_path` variable is necessary to serve each possible endpoint with
        `index.html` file in order to be compatible with `react-router-dom
        """
        return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

    return app
```

### Usage

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()

path_to_react_app_build_dir = "./frontend/build"
app = serve_react_app(app, path_to_react_app_build_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8001)
```

Comment: I have a question about this method. How do you know what host to specify in the react app when making calls to the FAST API other endpoints? For example, you have an endpoint in your API like `/books/{book_id}` and you want to call this endpoint from the react app that's served in this method. Your FASTAPI currently is on localhost, but you don't want to hardcode `localhost/books/{book_id}` how do you replace this 'localhost' with the IP FASTAPI server is running on?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 I am not really sure that I understood your question but I think that the answer to it is to tell you that by default, when you call `fetch` if you pass a route like "/favicon.ico" to the path parameter, it will automatically assume that the full path is `https://www.<current_domain>/favicon.ico`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a app structure like this:

```
├── main.py
└── routers
    └── my_router.py
```

And the routers we created in `my_router.py`

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/some")
async def some_path():
    pass

@router.get("/path")
async def some_other_path():
    pass

@router.post("/some_post_path")
async def some_post_path():
    pass
```

Let's dive in to the **`main.py`** first we need to import our router we declared with

```
from routers import my_router
```

Then let's create a **app** instance

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from routers import my_router

app = FastAPI()
```

So how do we add our routers?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from routers import my_router

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(my_router.router)
```

You can also add **prefix, tag, etc.**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from routers import my_router

app = FastAPI()


app.include_router(
    my_router.router,
    prefix="/custom_path",
    tags=["We are from router!"],
)
```

### Let's check the docs

[image]

Comment: You are still defining all the routes. 
Are you aware of this flask feature https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117464/4887475
We are looking for same

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of serving multiple routes (or lazy loading functions) using a single post url. The body of a request to the url would contain the name of a function to call and data to pass to the function if any. The `*.py` files in the `routes/` directory contain the functions, and functions share the same name as their files.

**project structure**

```
app.py
routes/
  |__helloworld.py
  |_*.py
```

**routes/helloworld.py**

```py
def helloworld(data):
    return data
```

**app.py**

```py
from os.path import split, realpath
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader as sfl
import uvicorn
from typing import Any
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

# set app's root directory 
API_DIR = split(realpath(__file__))[0]

class RequestPayload(BaseModel):
  """payload for post requests"""
  # function in `/routes` to call
  route: str = 'function_to_call'
  # data to pass to the function
  data: Any = None

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/api')
async def api(payload: RequestPayload):
    """post request to call function"""
  # load `.py` file from `/routes`
  route = sfl(payload.route,
    f'{API_DIR}/routes/{payload.route}.py').load_module()
  # load function from `.py` file
  func = getattr(route, payload.route)
  # check if function requires data
  if ('data' not in payload.dict().keys()):
    return func()
  return func(payload.data)
```

This example returns `{"hello": "world"}` with the post request below.

```sh
curl -X POST "http://localhost:70/api" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"route\":\"helloworld\",\"data\":{\"hello\": \"world\"}}"
```

The benefit of this setup is that a single post url can be used to complete any type of request (get, delete, put, etc), as the "type of request" is the logic defined in the function. For example, if `get_network.py` and `delete_network.py` are added to the `routes/` directory

**routes/get_network.py**

```py
def get_network(id: str):
  network_name = ''
  # logic to retrieve network by id from db
  return network_name
```

**routes/delete_network.py**

```py
def delete_network(id: str):
  network_deleted = False
  # logic to delete network by id from db
  return network_deleted
```

then a request payload of `{"route": "get_network", "data": "network_id"}` returns a network name, and `{"route": "delete_network", "data": "network_id"}` would return a boolean indicating wether the network was deleted or not.