# How to pass parameters to an endpoint using `add_route()` in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I'm developing a simple application with FastAPI.

I need a function to be called as endpoint for a certain route. Everything works just fine with the function's default parameters, but wheels come off the bus as soon as I try to override one of them.

Example. This works just fine:

```py
async def my_function(request=Request, clientname='my_client'):
    print(request.method)
    print(clientname)
    ## DO OTHER STUFF...
    return SOMETHING

private_router.add_route('/api/my/test/route', my_function, ['GET'])
```

This returns an error instead:

```py
async def my_function(request=Request, clientname='my_client'):
    print(request.method)
    print(clientname)
    ## DO OTHER STUFF...
    return SOMETHING

private_router.add_route('/api/my/test/route', my_function(clientname='my_other_client'), ['GET'])
```

The Error:

```bash
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60005 - "GET /api/my/test/route HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

The only difference is I'm trying to override the `clientname` value in `my_function`.

It is apparent that this isn't the right syntax but I looked everywhere and I'm just appalled that the documentation about the `add_route` method is nowhere to be found.

Is anyone able to point me to the right way to do this supposedly simple thing?

Thanks!

Comment: You're _calling_ the (endpoint) function, not registering it with a predetermined parameter - in that case you'd probaly want a helper function that returns an inner function - which is the function that should be registered to the endpoint (i.e. something like `def client(client_name): async def wrapped(): print(client_name) ... return wrapped`); this will bind the given `client_name` to the function that gets returned (which has the given values in the scope). This also matches that the API requirement for the function is (no parameters), since client_name is given when creating the api.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh, it's still not clear to me how to override that parameter in the route definition, once I wrapped the function. What the add_route definition should look like in my example? My need is to be able to pass different `clientname` values to different routes.

Comment: Hi @Chris, I tried both `:` and `=` the function works both ways. It returns the expected payload when called as in my first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

One way is to make a partial application of the function using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). As per `functools.partial`'s documentation:

> `functools.partial(func, /, *args, **keywords)`
>
> Return a new [partial object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects) which when called will behave like
> *func* called with the positional arguments *args* and keyword arguments *keywords*. If more arguments are supplied to the call, they
> are appended to *args*. If additional keyword arguments are supplied,
> they extend and override *keywords*. Roughly equivalent to:
>
> ```py
> def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
>     def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
>         newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
>         return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
>     newfunc.func = func
>     newfunc.args = args
>     newfunc.keywords = keywords
>     return newfunc
> ```
>
> The partial() is used for partial function application which "freezes"
> some portion of a function's arguments and/or keywords resulting in a
> new object with a simplified signature.

##### Working Example

Here is the source for the [`add_route()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/2168e47052239da5df35d5353bb986f760c51cef/starlette/routing.py#L773) method, as well as [the part in `Route` clas](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/2168e47052239da5df35d5353bb986f760c51cef/starlette/routing.py#L225)s where Starlette checks if the `endpoint_handler` that is passed to `add_route()` is an instance of `functools.partial`.

**Note** that the endpoint has to return an instance of `Response`/`JSONResponse`/etc., as returning a `str` or `dict` object (e.g., `return client_name`), for instance, would throw `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` or `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`, respectively. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details and examples on how to return JSON data using a custom `Response`.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, APIRouter, Response
from functools import partial


async def my_endpoint(request: Request, client_name: str ='my_client'):
    print(request.method)
    return Response(client_name)


app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()
router.add_route('/', partial(my_endpoint, client_name='my_other_client'), ['GET'])  
app.include_router(router)
```

### Option 2

As noted by @MatsLindh in the comments section, you could use a helper function that returns an inner function, which is essentially the same as using `functools.partial` in Option 1, as that is exactly how that function works under the hood (as shown in the quote block earlier).

##### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, APIRouter, Response

def my_endpoint(client_name: str ='my_client'): 
    async def newfunc(request: Request): 
        print(request.method)
        return Response(client_name)
    return newfunc

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()
router.add_route('/', my_endpoint(client_name='my_other_client'), ['GET'])  
app.include_router(router)
```

---

I would also suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77912313/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73295133/17865804), which demonstrate how to use `add_api_route()` instead of `add_route()`, which might be a better alternative, if you faced issues when using FastAPI `dependencies`.

Comment: Used Option 2 ant it works perfectly! Thank you so much @Chris! I still cannot wrap my head around the fact that it's impossible to find any documentation about this, I assume, quite common need...