# Accessing path variable in fastapi

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

I have fastapi endpoint

```
@app.post("/{ap_name}/{branch_name}")
```

Here branch is github repo branch name , that I need to capture
If user gives one word branch name then its fine,
if user gives branchname with slashes , like ap_name/**ap/rt**
Then it errors out.
Is there a mechanism where I can consider anything after {ap_name}/ as branch_name
i,e if user gives `ap_name/ap/rt....` Then can we map ap_rt to branch_name like   `{ap_name}/*..` in fastapi

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72815364/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers that you might find helpful can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72239186/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73295133/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `:path` property, as described in FastAPI's documentation here:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#path-convertor

Your endpoint would then be

```
@app.post("/{ap_name}/{branch_name:path}")
```

This should return the rest of the url as part of branch_name

Comment: This seems not working I gave 
@router.post("/{branch_name:path}")

and url as ex.com/v1/upload/main/th  I should have got branchname as /main/th but it gives error saying 404 not founf