# Serve static files from root in FastAPI

Tags: svelte, fastapi

I'm trying to have FastAPI work with Svelte. I've built the static files with Svelte and now I'm trying to serve them from FastAPI. The problem is that the built Svelte files reference e.g. `global.css` from root, which means I can't have them mounted on a subfolder.

Instead, I have to mount them on root:

```
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="web/public", html=True), name="web")
```

However, this makes anything defined in routes (function decorators) inaccessible.

Is it possible have either both static files *and* functions defined? Either,

a) routes take precedence and if there's no route, it tries to read from static directories

b) static directories take precedence, and I specify an exclude path, which goes to routes instead

Comment: Which built files reference `/global.css`? Usually the location of assets (global.css or bundle.js) is defined in a .html file

Comment: Take a look at sapper, it uses sirv for static files and then the sapper middleware for route handling : https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/blob/master/src/server.js

Comment: I actually resorted to using Flask - this functionality works there.

Answer (score 18):

Create an outer (root) FastAPI app and mount the StaticFiles app and your existing FastAPI app inside of it.

```
# Your main app must be first!
app = FastAPI(title="my app root")

api_app = FastAPI(title="my existing api")
api_app.include_router(my_existing_router)
app.mount('/api', api_app)

app.mount('/', StaticFiles(directory="static", html=True), name="static")
```

The order of mounting of the app objects seems to matter. For the OpenAPI docs, you'll have a `/docs` for the root app, and a `/api/docs` for your API app.

Comment: i posted an answer that neither requires as second app instance nor a router.

Answer (score 16):

I think there's an even easier solution than those posted here: Simply mount your static folder **after** the definition of your other endpoints.

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/api/hello")
async def hello():
    return "hello from fastapi"

app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="build", html=True), name="frontend")
```

You can now access the website served as a static site on root while also accessing the endpoints you might want to use for backend functionality.

Comment: Even though your example works, I had to revert to the top answer of @idrg, because somehow I was getting a "405 method not allowed" on a POST request. Odd, but this problem was resolved without any modification to the code by creating an outer (root) FastAPI app.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without creating an "outer (root) app"; as long as you mount the static files after you include your routers.

assuming you have:

- fastAPI app in "project/main.py"
- svelte stuff in "project/client"
- "a_router" in a file "project/subfolder/do_stuff.py"

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse

from subfolder.do_stuff import a_router 

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(a_router)

app.mount("", StaticFiles(directory="client/public", html=True), name="client")
app.mount("/build", StaticFiles(directory="client/public/build"), name="build")

@app.get('/')
async def client():  return RedirectResponse(url="client")
```